# How to move from one class to other class in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know how to move from one class to other class in android.
I have one main class i.e Addition.java(Main Activity) and i created other subactivity(Form.java). 
I want to how to make my move from one class(ie.Activity)to other.

I tried this,but not working out,just trying to figure out

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this.getParent(),Form.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

here Form.class is the subactivity, this.getParent I hope it represents main activity. And I created one activity in manifest.xml file and named it as .Form

Am i working right?

Comment: Is it not working or are there any compilation errors?

Comment: Hey it's not working,i wrote this under button click,when i press the button it shows exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works perfectly. 
Try it:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(v.getContext(),Form.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that activity is declared in Android.manifest.

Comment: Hi Guys,I got my problem cleared,pblm is due to fact that i created constructor for that activity similar to java class,after removing it,it worked fine

Thanks for your help guys